# Как работает МАА? Откуда взять константы и переменные?

Tags: криптография, хеширование, аутентификация

Доброго дня, надо реализовать алгоритм хэширования MAA(Message Authenticator Algorithm) для проверки подлинности участников криптопротокола, но что гугление, что Шнайер выдают лишь эту небольшую часть:

"Этот алгоритм является стандартом ISO. Он выдает 32-битовое хэш-значение и был спроектирован для мэйнфреймов с быстрыми инструкциями умножения.

v=v<<<1

e=v xor w

x=((((e+y) mod 2^32)۷A۸C)*(x xor Mi))mod 2^32-1

y=((((e+x) mod 2^32)۷B۸D)*(y xor Mi))mod 2^32-1

Эти действия повторяются для каждого блока сообщений, Mi, и результирующее хэш-значение получается с помощью XOR x и y. Переменные v и e зависят от ключа. A, B, C и D являются константами. Возможно, этот алгоритм широко используется, но он недостаточно безопасен. Он разработан давно и не слишком сложен."

Так вот мой вопрос состоит в следующем: откуда берутся(или по каким правилам генерируются) константы и переменные в данном алгоритме?

Answer (score -1):

Википедия гласит:

> A <- 0x02040801
> B <- 0x00804021
> C <- 0xbfef7fdf
> D <- 0x7dfefbff

Очевидно, что это в A и B установлено 4 единичных бита, а в C и D - наоборот сброшены.
Получение W, V и так далее тоже описано в Википедии, перепечатывать смысла не вижу.